# Kolla-ansible too many open files

Tags: openstack

I am having an issue with a relatively small openstack cluster deployed with kolla-ansible. The issue is that after a few days the controllers stop working. When I go into the docker container logs, I see in all of them that there are Too Many Open Files. I have tried changing limits.conf sysctl max files for processes and user. After all of that, the issue still shows up.

One interesting thing is that this was not happening until I had to reboot all of the controllers. I rebooted them because I needed to increase the amount of ram that they have after they died swapping. My first thought was that kolla-ansible is setting a configuration after running deploy, but I can't seem to find any point in the repo when kolla-ansible is changing ulimits or other.

Any theories what could cause this? Would it be related to increasing ram? Should I run reconfigure/deploy on each controller? I've tried looking in kolla-ansible's docs and forums and couldn't see where anyone else was having this issue.

Update this hasn't been fixed yet:
I submitted a bug report, https://bugs.launchpad.net/kolla-ansible/+bug/1901898

Comment: Which containers are showing that message?. I'm not familiar with kolla at all, but a customer also had "too many open files" in a simple cloud setup (one control node, a dozen compute nodes, no containers). In that case it was apache that was limited to 1024 but requested more (many users accessing keystone, dashboard etc.). I created a drop-in file for apache and increased the value to something like 16k or so (`systemctl edit apache`).

Comment: The one that I check once they break is Memcached but essentially all of them have some iteration of the too many files error. I forgot to mention I also checked to make sure that docker ulimits were set high enough and they seemed to be set to INFINITY.

Comment: Maybe someone else with more knowledge about docker and kolla can help out, I have only been dealing with single systemd units that required a higher limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed with a workaround in bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/keystonemiddleware/+bug/1883659 problem was neutron server was keeping memcached connections open and not closing them until the memcached container reached too many files open. There is a work around mentioned in the bug link.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your used versions of Kolla-Ansible and your Linux, but your problem seems really related to this one:

`On Ubuntu 16.04, please uninstall lxd and lxc packages. (An issue exists with cgroup mounts, mounts exponentially increasing when restarting container)` (source: docs.openstack.org/kolla-ansible/4.0.0/quickstart.html)

I had this problem with the exponentially growing number of mount-pointers after the restart of my docker-containers too. My single-node test-deployment had become very slow based on this problem, but I can't remember at the moment, that I would had the same error with too many open files.

You can delete the packages with `apt-get remove lxc-common lxcfs lxd lxd-client`. I had done this fix together with a complete reinstallation of the kolla-ansible installation, so I don't know, if this also helps with an already existing installation. You should also use `docker-ce` instead of the docker from the apt-repos.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm using CentOS 8 and version kolla-ansible version 10.1. It install docker version 19.03.12 using bootstrap. Let me mess with the lxd/lxc concept on there to see if it exists.

Comment: Doesn't seem any of those packages are installed. I reran deploy on one of the controllers so I will wait to see if it does it again on that one. It takes a few days for it to happen. My theory is something is modified during bootstrap/deploy or something else that when increasing ram amount for a virtual machine/vmware openstack controller after first deploy breaks something. If the redeploy doesn't work I'll wipe that controller and redeploy from scratch though that isn't a fix :D.